# CallKit is not get updated on iPhone 14 with Dynamic Island

Tags: swift, iphone, callkit

When I am receiving incoming call I need to update localizedCallerName in CallKit, all works good with other iPhone models, but with new iPhone 14 localizedCallerName is not changed.

Is there anything I should specify to update the name with new iPhone?

This is the code I use for updating caller name:

```
func updateCall(_ call: Call) {
    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = call.otherParty.cxHandle
    update.localizedCallerName = call.otherParty.localizedCallerName
    update.hasVideo = false
    cxProvider.reportCall(with: call.uuid, updated: update)
}
```